# How to store Sharethis Values in the Database?

Tags: views, database, social-network

I am using the [Sharethis](https://drupal.org/project/sharethis) Module and i want to sort some views by the number of total shares. But if i am understanding it correctly the values are not stored in the drupal database. Instead they are pulled from the Sharethis Servers.
How can i store these values in the Drupal Database ?

Comment: Pull them from sharethis servers the same way module does? In hook_cron, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Social Stats](https://drupal.org/sandbox/ajgit/2080003) module to do that.

> This is a statistics module. It provides data from various social media sites. The data which is saved per node includes data from:
>
> 1. Facebook : likes count, shares count, comments count & total count.
> 2. Twitter : tweets count.
> 3. LinkedIn : share count.
> 4. Google Plus : plus one count
> 5. Total shares

Note: This is a sandbox project. I'm the author of the module.